# merging 2 array of objects using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have

```
seatsArray=  { seat_number: "1K" },
    { seat_number: "2K" },
    { seat_number: "3K"},
    { seat_number: "5K" },
    { seat_number: "6K" },
    { seat_number: "7K" },
    { seat_number: "8K" },
    { seat_number: "9K" },
    { seat_number: "10K" },
    { seat_number: "11K" },

foodarray = [{
  "age": 41,
  "gender": "Woman",
  "holdSeatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fe6",
  "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b5329",
  "PAXName": "Jianmin Hui",
  "seatName": "22A",
  "seatType": "EC",
  "vip": false,
  "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63",
  "foodTypeId": "632000e0cdcfde6b6088001a",
  "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b66",
  "orderType": "Pre_Ordered",
  "qty": 1,
  "seatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fe6"},{
  "age": 44,
  "gender": "Woman",
  "holdSeatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d79",
  "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b532b",
  "PAXName": "Pei Li",
  "seatName": "10K",
  "seatType": "BC",
  "vip": false,
  "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63",
  "foodTypeId": "6295bb887115c2151edef87d",
  "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b71",
  "orderType": "Special_Meal",
  "qty": 1,
  "seatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d79",
  "description": "Chicken Noodles",
  "foodCatergoryDescription": "Meal with Meat",
  "fullName": "Chicken Noodles" }]
```

i want to compare these 2 array of objects and merge to form a new array of objects ONLY if seat_number = seatName eg 10K , without including info for 22a in the final payload given it is not in the original seat list

Comment: tried const map = new Map();
bc1.forEach(item => map.set(item.seat_number, item));
tunedPreorder.forEach(item => map.set(item.seatName, {...map.get(item.seatName), ...item}));
const mergedArr1 = Array.from(map.values());    ..............output includes 22a, which i want to exclude

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `seatsArray` to create a new array based on the `seatsArray` and `foodarray`.

We can use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to determine if there is a matching item in the foodarray for each item.

If there is a matching food item we append it to the seat object using [`destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const seatsArray=  [{ seat_number: "1K" }, { seat_number: "2K" }, { seat_number: "3K"}, { seat_number: "5K" }, { seat_number: "6K" }, { seat_number: "7K" }, { seat_number: "8K" }, { seat_number: "9K" }, { seat_number: "10K" }, { seat_number: "11K" }]
const foodarray = [{ "age": 41, "gender": "Woman", "holdSeatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fe6", "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b5329", "PAXName": "Jianmin Hui", "seatName": "22A", "seatType": "EC", "vip": false, "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63", "foodTypeId": "632000e0cdcfde6b6088001a", "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b66", "orderType": "Pre_Ordered", "qty": 1, "seatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fe6"},{ "age": 44, "gender": "Woman", "holdSeatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d79", "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b532b", "PAXName": "Pei Li", "seatName": "10K", "seatType": "BC", "vip": false, "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63", "foodTypeId": "6295bb887115c2151edef87d", "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b71", "orderType": "Special_Meal", "qty": 1, "seatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d79", "description": "Chicken Noodles", "foodCatergoryDescription": "Meal with Meat", "fullName": "Chicken Noodles" }] 

const result = seatsArray.map((seat) => {
    const food = foodarray.find(food => food.seatName === seat.seat_number);
    return food ? ({ ...seat, ...food }): seat;
});

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you only want to show seats with a matching order you can use map, then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const seatsArray=  [{ seat_number: "1K" }, { seat_number: "2K" }, { seat_number: "3K"}, { seat_number: "5K" }, { seat_number: "6K" }, { seat_number: "7K" }, { seat_number: "8K" }, { seat_number: "9K" }, { seat_number: "10K" }, { seat_number: "11K" }]
const foodarray = [{ "age": 41, "gender": "Woman", "holdSeatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fe6", "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b5329", "PAXName": "Jianmin Hui", "seatName": "22A", "seatType": "EC", "vip": false, "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63", "foodTypeId": "632000e0cdcfde6b6088001a", "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b66", "orderType": "Pre_Ordered", "qty": 1, "seatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fe6"},{ "age": 44, "gender": "Woman", "holdSeatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d79", "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b532b", "PAXName": "Pei Li", "seatName": "10K", "seatType": "BC", "vip": false, "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63", "foodTypeId": "6295bb887115c2151edef87d", "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b71", "orderType": "Special_Meal", "qty": 1, "seatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d79", "description": "Chicken Noodles", "foodCatergoryDescription": "Meal with Meat", "fullName": "Chicken Noodles" }] 

const result = seatsArray.map((seat) => {
    const food = foodarray.find(food => food.seatName === seat.seat_number);
    return food ? ({ ...seat, ...food }): seat;
}).filter(row => row.foodTypeId);

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Or you could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const seatsArray=  [{ seat_number: "1K" }, { seat_number: "2K" }, { seat_number: "3K"}, { seat_number: "5K" }, { seat_number: "6K" }, { seat_number: "7K" }, { seat_number: "8K" }, { seat_number: "9K" }, { seat_number: "10K" }, { seat_number: "11K" }]
const foodarray = [{ "age": 41, "gender": "Woman", "holdSeatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fe6", "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b5329", "PAXName": "Jianmin Hui", "seatName": "22A", "seatType": "EC", "vip": false, "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63", "foodTypeId": "632000e0cdcfde6b6088001a", "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b66", "orderType": "Pre_Ordered", "qty": 1, "seatId": "6417f5440c5374a4d72b4fe6"},{ "age": 44, "gender": "Woman", "holdSeatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d79", "id": "6417f56a0c5374a4d72b532b", "PAXName": "Pei Li", "seatName": "10K", "seatType": "BC", "vip": false, "containerId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b63", "foodTypeId": "6295bb887115c2151edef87d", "locationId": "6417f5180c5374a4d72b4b71", "orderType": "Special_Meal", "qty": 1, "seatId": "63282c0952dba06a20b52d79", "description": "Chicken Noodles", "foodCatergoryDescription": "Meal with Meat", "fullName": "Chicken Noodles" }] 

const result = seatsArray.reduce((acc, seat) => {
    const food = foodarray.find(food => food.seatName === seat.seat_number);
    if (food) { 
        acc.push({ ...seat, ...food });
    }
    return acc;
}, []);

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```